# Select all td in tr with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

How would I access all of the tds in a tr, knowing only the tr index. I am hoping to do this with the jQuery nth-child selector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$("table tr:eq(5) td")
```

This returns all td elements in the 6th row of a table

Answer (score 6):

The uber-speedy [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) filter method is one way.

```
var $cells = $("#table tr").eq(index).find("td");
```

Comment: First time I hear of .eq and definitely this is going to my favorites! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table tr:nth-child(x) td");
```

This will return all the td within the x you set